# Select a variable from an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, if-statement, refer

I am new to php arrays. I can not find the solution.

This is my code:

```
$animals = Array
            (
            1=>$duck,
            2=>$horse,
            3=>$rabbit
            );

            ForEach($animals As $animal) 
            {
                echo $animals[Array_Rand($animals)];
            }
```

And now I want to select a suitable variable from the array, which is the $rabbit.

Something like:

```
if($animal[3]){
                echo 'The rabbit just spawned';
            }
```

I please, tell me how to refer to the variable number 3 (rabbit) using if instruction.

Comment: `if($animal[3]){` — What is this condition supposed to do? Are you trying to check if the random element you just selected is rabbit? Or something else?

Comment: `echo Array_Rand($animals) == 3 ? 'The rabbit just spawned' : '';` – like this ?

Comment: Yes, I create a captcha. They have to select a rabbit. I do not like number-ccaptcha :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a for each loop for this, just a random to choose from the array:

https://eval.in/162384

```
$animals = Array
            (
            1=>'duck',
            2=>'horse',
            3=>'rabbit'
            );
$dieroll=array_rand($animals);
echo "The $animals[$dieroll] just spawned.";
```

Result:

> The duck just spawned.

Edit: you mentioned wanting to choose 3 from the array. Then you can use `array_rand($x,3)`:

https://eval.in/162392

```
$animals = Array
            (
            1=>'duck',
            2=>'horse',
            3=>'rabbit',
            4=>'bear',
            5=>'moose'
            );
$dierolls=array_rand($animals,3);
// randomize the order of the dierolls:
shuffle($dierolls);
foreach($dierolls as $dieroll) {
    echo "Look out, it's a $animals[$dieroll]!\n";
};
```

Gives:

> Look out, it's a duck!
>
> Look out, it's a rabbit!
>
> Look out, it's a bear!

Comment: It is nice, but the only duck spawns. I need to spawn 3 animals at the same time and if there is a duck, then it says 'the duck spawned'.

Comment: to make this more scaleable, you could change `$dieroll=rand(1,3);` to `$dieroll=array_rand($animals);` so as the array changes, so can the random key.

Comment: Thanks. But there should spawn 3 monsters, not only one.

Comment: Edited based on @Sean's suggestion... glapa.wojciech You never mentioned that... so is it possible to spawn rabbit, rabbit, rabbit, or do they each have to be unique?

Comment: I was thinking about captcha for my site. I got on my mind that I do something like this: To register account select duck from horse, duck and rabbit. If they click horse, then it spawns random again: rabbit duck horse and now they have to select a rabbit etc. :P

Comment: Great! does it protect from spawning the same animals? I mean $dierolls=array_rand($animals, 3);

Comment: Yes, it will choose 3 distinct records from the array.

Comment: I accept your answer, but if You want You can still help me at something. How to spawn they at random place in row? It means: instead of spawning always duck, horse, bear, then spawn horse, bear, duck or duck, bear, horse/

Comment: If you want to randomize the order they appear, use [shuffle()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.shuffle.php): https://eval.in/162400

Comment: Thank You so much, friend :) You just made my life today :)